# Linked List With Iterator

Tags: java, list, linked-list, iterator, listiterator

everyone. I have to make a sandwich with certain ingredients and need to iterate between some elements of the linked list to insert certain toppings. I need some help on the last two parts of my code where I have to insert bacon between chicken and tomato. For some reason, bacon is showing up at the very end between salt and Bread2. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time.

```
/*
 Date: 03/27/2016
 Purpose: Demonstrate Use and Knowledge of LinkedList and Iterator. You CAN'T use an index number for inserting elements into
 linked list. You must only use the list iterator. Submit one java file only. 
*/
import java.util.List;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.ListIterator;

public class LinkedListDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
  {

    List<String> myLinkedList = new LinkedList<String>();

    String strOutput="";

    //BUILD THE SANDWICH

    myLinkedList.add("Bread1");
    myLinkedList.add("mustard");
    myLinkedList.add("lettuce");
    myLinkedList.add("chicken");
    myLinkedList.add("tomato");
    myLinkedList.add("Bread2");

    ListIterator<String> lit = myLinkedList.listIterator();

    while(lit.hasNext()) 
    {
      strOutput += (lit.next().toString() + ",") ;
    }
   strOutput +=("You have reached the end of the sandwich.\n");


   //SHOW THE CURRENT SANDWICH IN REVERSE USING "PREVIOUS()" METHOD
    while(lit.hasPrevious())
    {
        strOutput += (lit.previous().toString() + ",");
    }
    strOutput +=("You have reached the end of the sandwich.\n");


    //ADD PICKLES BETWEEN LETTUCE AND CHICKEN
    while(lit.hasNext())
    {
        if(lit.next().toString().equals("lettuce"))
        {
            lit.add("pickles");
            break;
        }
    }

    while(lit.hasPrevious())
    {
        lit.previous();
    }

    while(lit.hasNext()) 
    {
      strOutput += (lit.next().toString() + ",") ;
    }
   strOutput +=("You have reached the end of the sandwich.\n");


   //ADD CHEESE BETWEEN TOMATO AND BREAD2
   while(lit.hasPrevious())
   {
       if(lit.previous().toString().equals("Bread2"))
       {
          lit.add("cheese");
          break;
       }
   }

   while(lit.hasPrevious())
   {
       lit.previous();
   }

   while(lit.hasNext())
   {
       strOutput += (lit.next().toString() + ",");
   }
   strOutput += ("You have the reached the end of the sandwich.\n");


    //ADD SALT BETWEEN CHEESE AND BREAD2
   while(lit.hasPrevious())
   {
       if(lit.previous().toString().equals("Bread2"))
       {
          lit.add("salt");
          break;
       }
   }

   while(lit.hasPrevious())
    {
       lit.previous();
    }

   while(lit.hasNext())
    {
       strOutput += (lit.next().toString() + ",");
    }
    strOutput += ("You have the reached the end of the sandwich.\n");


   //GO BACKWARDS AND INSERT BACON BETWEEN CHICKEN AND TOMATO
    while(lit.hasPrevious())    
    {
        if(lit.previous().toString().equals("chicken"));
        {
            lit.add("bacon");
            break;
        }
    }

    while(lit.hasPrevious())
    {
        lit.previous();
    }

    while(lit.hasNext())
    {
        strOutput += (lit.next().toString() + ",");
    }
    strOutput += ("You have the reached the end of the sandwich.\n");


    //SHOW FINAL SANDWICH IN FORWARD ORDER

    javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, strOutput);
    System.exit(0);
  }

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19614083/2055998

Comment: Only problem is that I can not use an index.

Comment: Have you looked at the particular solution I linked to?

Comment: I did but can't seem to figure it out

Comment: You need to do `lit.previous` before `add`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo:

```
    if(lit.previous().toString().equals("chicken")); // <-- semi-colon
    {
        lit.add("bacon");
        break;
    }
```

EDIT:

The semi-colon closes the if statement early. This means `lit.add("bacon");` is always run, regardless of the if statement.

Comment: It's always the stupid things that get me. Thank you. For the last part, how do I print out the statement in the message dialog? I don't know why the message dialog isn't showing.

Comment: I've also took the javax.swing. in the same line of JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(), upstairs with the imports(import javax.swing.*;